# Convert 1-D array into sparse matrix

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, sparse-matrix

I am working on a recommendation project where I have data like this:

```
ID Movie
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
..
..
```

I want to create this dataframe into a sparse matrix like this:

```
     1  2  3  4 ....n

1    1  0  0  0     0
2    0  1  0  0     0
3    0  0  1  0     0
4    0  0  0  1     0
.
.
n    0  0  0  0     1
```

Basically both rows and columns contains the ID of the move, and the value is 1 when both row and column element has same value. I want to represent this into  a sparse format of

```
 <sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 58770 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

I tried doing the following:

```
 - np.diag(items)
 - csr_matrix(items.values)
```

But I am not able to figure it out. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you specify a bit better an exact input and an expected output? (ideally something that could just be copy-pasted into a Python script)

Comment: What happened with each of your attempts? Did you get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [scipy.sparse.spdiags](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.spdiags.html)

```
num_data=len(df)
sp=sparse.spdiags(np.ones(num_data), 0, num_data,num_data)
```

OUTPUT

```
  (0, 0)    1.0
  (1, 1)    1.0
  (2, 2)    1.0
  (3, 3)    1.0
```

If `ID` of the movie is not consistent:

```
sparse.coo_matrix((np.ones(num_data),(df['ID'],df['ID'])))
```

if `ID` is from two different dataframe:

```
match=list(set(df['ID']).intersection(set(df2['ID'])))
sparse.coo_matrix((np.ones(num_data),(match,match)))
```

Answer (score 1):

A matrix with ones down the diagonal and zeros everywhere else is called an "identity matrix". You can create one in python with  `scipy.sparse.identity(n)`. The documentation is [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.identity.html).